# Tool/Library for Periodic Job Scheduling (e.g. polling web pages)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scheduling, resque

Is there a tool/framework available to support periodically polling various resources? e.g. I have in mind an RSS aggregator which would check for new content once a day, or a tool to maintain a cache of users' Twitter's avatar, which would poll their Twitter account once a week.

I'm not looking for the tools to perform the actual fetching or feed-processing; I'm looking for something which would store date of last fetch, wake up when the next one is due, etc.

Messaging tools like Resque and Delayed Job are optimised for "time-shifting" specific incoming requests rather than handling periodic tasks. In other words, I don't think you'd want to keep a perpetual job around for every user to retrieve their Twitter avatar. But I stand to be corrected :D.

Comment: Maybe, but it needs to deal with the fact that it might not process everything fast enough to be done between alarms/wake-ups. ie the period probably needs to be variable, which is why I thought scheduling makes more sense, ie "do this again at least one week later".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anacron is great for this. We have it wake up once a day to trigger background fetching. The background fetcher does a query to SQL to find the next N users who need updates, then does that batch.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron

"It performs periodic command scheduling which is traditionally done by cron, but without assuming that the system is running continuously. Thus, it can be used to control the execution of daily, weekly, and monthly jobs on systems that don't run 24 hours a day.

Anacron makes sure that these commands are run at the specified intervals as closely as machine uptime permits."

Answer (score 1):

We've used this https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler and its served our needs. You write a cron like yml file and the jobs are scheduled just like resque jobs. I'd recommend this if you're already using resque.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask if you've used it for this kind of thing - many thousands of periodic jobs?

Comment: it will work for that yes, I've used it to queue thousands of jobs. they're just entries in redis which cron queries after all.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Your requirement of dying and waking up on demand seems too ideal to have been pre-built into a library. If your daemon dies after it does its job, you'd again need another daemon/running-task to guide it to wake up when necessary, and that's not what you'd want.

That being said, you might give a try using `foreverb` as a custom daemon for such tasks. It is pretty simple and efficient and you get to isolate your parts. One script where you write your requirement and then one daemon to run it.

https://github.com/DAddYE/foreverb

If you find what you're looking for, make sure you let the world know.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I've created this kind of thing with the daemons gem; the problem is various logic gets duplicated for different kinds of tasks.